# JavaScript string replacement

Tags: javascript

I have a string with comma separated values:

```
var x = '1,2,10,11,12';
```

I need to remove the value that's in y.

```
x = remove(x,y);
```

Q: Is there a function for that already or do I need to convert it to an array, remove y and then convert it back to a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `x.replace(y, "")`. For more information, see the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: *just that* won't be enough but it's an interesting starting point

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the problem. Are you matching strings, or numeric values in y?

Comment: Just keep in mind that using a string for the first parameter will only replace the value once. Doing `String.replace(/value/g, "");` will replace all instances of it.

Comment: I think if I put a leading comma and a trailing comma in x, then I can do: x.replace(',' + y + ',',",")

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn, that won't work when y is at the beginning or end of the list.  Without the commas won't work because you might remove numbers you don't want.  If y is '7', for example, you could turn '17' into '1'.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your removing 'y' where y is an index, do this:

```
x = x.split(',').splice(y,1).join(',');
```

Edit:

In that case, I would use regex. If you wish to avoid regex, another solution is available:

```
while(x.indexOf(y) >= 0){
 x.replace(y+',', '');
}
```

EDIT: Added a trailing comma to the replace, such that the list remains a comma delimited list.

Comment: y is not an index.  y is a value.  In this example, it would be customer ids or product ids.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
var arr = "1,2,1,2,3".split(",");
var arr2 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] != "1") arr2.push(arr[i])
}
arr2.join(","); // "2,2,3"
```

Comment: This is grossly ugly code, I can't imagine why you would ever use this as a solution to OP question.

Comment: Why would you declare an anonymous string and then split it? why would you use a second array to copy every single negative match, rather then just removing the positive ones?

Comment: The OP has a string which needs certain elements removed, at least that's what I thought. I agree it's not the most elegant solution though.

Comment: Elegant no, but efficiency is the true problem here.

Answer (score 0):

`str_replace` analogon from phpjs.org:
http://phpjs.org/functions/str_replace:527

So you could use something like `x=str_replace(y, '', x);` ;) Or implement it yourself by using regexp!

Edit: Okay I think I got it wrong. Probably Greg's answer is the right one :-)

Comment: PHP.js intrigues, confuses, and disgusts me, much like a 12 year old arguing religion in a chat room, or a cockroach slowly making its way through the middle of my pudding.

Comment: -1 For recommending PHPjs. You don't need that. It's only use case is strict deadlines and talented PHP developers (who know no javascript).

Answer (score 0):

There are three things to check for

1. y at the beginning of the string and followed by a comma
2. y preceeded by a word break and followed by a comma
3. y at the end of the string and preceeded by a comma

   ```
   x.replace(new RegExp('((^|\\b)' + y + ',|,' + y +'$)'),'');
   ```